# Disabling keypad on arduino microcontroller using C Programming

Tags: c, arduino

We have a prototype that changes large bills into smaller bills. We are using an arduino microcontroller attatched with a keypad, the user should press the "0" button on the keypad in order for the machine to start a transaction. The user can input a value to choose their type of denominations. For example, if you insert a 100 dollar bill inside the machine, the user could choose if he wants to have it as two 50 dollar bills, or five 20 dollar bills.

The problem with our prototype is that when the machine detects that there is no money left for a transaction, the user could still use the machine for another transaction. There is a "bug" in our coding that if you randomly press all of the keys. The user could press "0" to start the transaction. We want to disable the keypad if the machine detects that there is no money left for another transaction.

Here is the code if the machine detects that there is no bill. And it also notifies the owner if there are no bills.

```
void SupChkU(){
    sLBill5H = digitalRead(LBill5H);
    if (sLBill5H == HIGH){
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Low in resources");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Please see owner");
        delay(100);
        Serial.println("500 Bills is empty ");
        if (SLvlBill5H == false){
            SLvlBill5H = true;
            textForSMS = "500 Bills is empty, please refill ";
            sendSMS(textForSMS);
        }  
        readkeyboard();
        if (keypressed == 11){
            RefillS();
        }  
    }

    sLBill1H = digitalRead(LBill1H);
    if (sLBill1H == HIGH){
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Low in resources");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Please see owner");
        delay(100);
        Serial.println("100 Bills is empty ");
        if (SLvlBill1H == false){
            SLvlBill1H = true;
            textForSMS = "100 Bills is empty, please refill ";
            sendSMS(textForSMS);
        }  
        readkeyboard();
        if (keypressed == 11){
            RefillS();
        }  
    }

    sLBill50 = digitalRead(LBill50);
    if (sLBill50 == HIGH){
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Low in resources");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Please see owner");
        delay(100);
        Serial.println("50 Bills is empty ");
        if (SLvlBill50 == false){
            SLvlBill50 = true;
            textForSMS = "50 Bills is empty, please refill ";
            sendSMS(textForSMS);
        }  
        readkeyboard();
        if (keypressed == 11){
            RefillS();
        }  
    }

    if (CntB5H < 10){
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Low in resources");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Please see owner");
        delay(100);
        Serial.println("PhP 500 Bills Low Level");
        if (SLvlBill5H == false){
            SLvlBill5H = true;
            textForSMS = " Low Level on PhP 500 Bills, please refill ";
            sendSMS(textForSMS);
        }  
        readkeyboard();
        if (keypressed == 11){
            RefillS();
        }
    }

    if (CntB1H < 10){
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Low in resources");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Please see owner");
        delay(100);
        Serial.println("PhP 100 Bills Low Level");
        if (SLvlBill1H == false){
            SLvlBill1H = true;
            textForSMS = " Low Level on PhP 100 Bills, please refill ";
            sendSMS(textForSMS);
        }  
        readkeyboard();
        if (keypressed == 11){
            RefillS();
        }
    }

    if (CntB50 < 10){
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Low in resources");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Please see owner");
        delay(100);
        Serial.println("PhP 50 Bills Low Level");
        if (SLvlBill50 == false){
            SLvlBill50 = true;
            textForSMS = " Low Level on PhP 50 Bills, please refill ";
            sendSMS(textForSMS);
        }  
        readkeyboard();
        if (keypressed == 11){
            RefillS();
        }
    }

    sLCoin1 = digitalRead(LCoin1); 
    if (sLCoin1 == HIGH){
        LvlC1 = true;
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Low for 1 Peso  ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Please see owner");
        Serial.println(" Low Level for 1 Peso Bin ");
        delay(1000);
        if (SLvlC1 == false){
            SLvlC1 = true;
            textForSMS = " Low Level for 1 Peso Bin ";
            sendSMS(textForSMS);
        }  
    }
    if (sLCoin1 == LOW){
        SLvlC1 = false;
    }   

    sLCoin5 = digitalRead(LCoin5); 
    if (sLCoin5 == HIGH){
        LvlC5 = true;
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Low for 5 Peso  ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Please see owner");
        Serial.println(" Low Level for 5 Peso Bin ");
        delay(1000);
        if (SLvlC5 == false){
            SLvlC5 = true;
            textForSMS = " Low Level for 5 Peso Bin ";
            sendSMS(textForSMS);
        }  
    }
    if (sLCoin5 == LOW){
        SLvlC5 = false;
    }

    sLCoin10 = digitalRead(LCoin10); 
    if (sLCoin10 == HIGH){
        LvlC10 = true;
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Low for 10 Peso ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Please see owner");
        Serial.println(" Low Level for 10 Peso Bin ");
        delay(1000);
        if (SLvlC10 == false){
            SLvlC10 = true;
            textForSMS = " Low Level for 10 Peso Bin ";
            sendSMS(textForSMS);
        }  
    }    
    if (sLCoin10 == LOW){
        SLvlC10 = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: good post. But where is your question?

Comment: This is not C! Arduino in general is not C.

Answer (score 0):

If the keypad is connected on SPI (MISO, MOSI, SCK, ...) (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface) you can disable it by disabling the interface:

1) set the PRSPI (?) bit in the PRR (power reduction register) to '1'

2) unset (set '0') the SPE bit (SPI Enable) in the SPCR register (?) (SPI Control Register)

see the datasheet of your processor for this, **maybe the register and bit naming varies**

The same method (disabling the interface) works also if the keypad is connected on UART ,...